# Error TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null mnthly @ submitPayslip.gs:117

Tags: function, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm having an error on my app script. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGkln.jpg)

```
function mnthly () {
  var ss, s1, data, outdata, s2;
  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  s1 = ss.getSheetByName("Paycheck");
  data = s1.getDataRange().getValues();
  outdata = [data[3][2], data[4][2], data[5][2], data[2][7], data[3][7],
             data[11][4], data[11][8], data[13][6], data[14][6],
             data[16][2], data[16][3], data[17][2],
             data[17][6], data[17][7], data[17][8],
             data[18][6], data[18][7], data[18][8]];
  s2 = ss.getSheetByName(data[2][7]);
  s2.getRange(s2.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, outdata.length).setValues([outdata]);           
}

TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null
mnthly  @ submitPayslip.gs:117
```

What I did on that is I need to separate the paychecks by month. What should I edit this one?

Comment: In that case, I thought that `s2` might be `null`. So, how about confirming whether the sheet name of `data[2][7]` is existing in the Spreadsheet?

Comment: @Tanaike Hi, yes. I did confirm that the sheet name of data [2][7] is existing in the Spreadsheet. The data [2][7], is a data validation from list specifically the months (Jan, Feb, March and so on), but I did make sure that the months exists and have their own sheets

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your script, when you confirmed the value of `s2` of `s2 = ss.getSheetByName(data[2][7]);`, what value did you get?

Comment: @Tanaike sorry, i'm little lost. Whenever I run the script, the value of s2=ss.getSheetByName(data[2][7]) doesn't show up to where it should be. That is supposed to be a month appearing on its own sheet. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I couldn't understand `Whenever I run the script, the value of s2=ss.getSheetByName(data[2][7]) doesn't show up to where it should be. That is supposed to be a month appearing on its own sheet. Does this answer your question?`. And I coudln't also understand the value of `s2` of `s2 = ss.getSheetByName(data[2][7]);` you confirfmed. I apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: @Tanaike No worries, its fine. I may have answered your question wrong  My bad. But for you to see the whole picture, do you want me to share the link of the sheet for you?

Comment: Thank for replying. If you can provide the sample Spreasheet for replicaing your issue, I can also confirm it.

Comment: @Tanaike here is the link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18PNOM1dnWvJYb_i5_Ilq0A4BOtch9R0cMM-WuxOAqRI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you for providing the sample Spreadsheet. When I saw your Spreadsheet, it seems that `outdata` is `["","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""]`. By this, `s2` of `s2 = ss.getSheetByName(data[2][7]);` is `null`. I think that the reason of your issue is clearly due to this. But, unfortunately, I cannot understand your goal. So I cannot still propose the modified script. This is due to my poor English skill. I apologize for this.

Comment: It seems that the value of `data[2][7]` is the dropdown list. For example, in your script, how about running the script when the value of `data[2][7]` is existing? For this, how about modifying `s2.getRange(s2.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, outdata.length).setValues([outdata]);` to `if (s2) s2.getRange(s2.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, outdata.length).setValues([outdata]);`? In this case, the error is removed.

Comment: @Tanaike Hi again, sorry for the late reply! I have found the error why I cannot get my desired output. Thank you for your answer, I realized why I did get the error. Thank you so much and stay safe! 

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience and in my own error in my script, make sure that the fields are not empty especially the "outdata" (in my script) especially in the 'data [2][7]'. You should run the script after you put the information.

Debug your script if you have an error to know where you went wrong, and if it null, put data on those fields where you need to put.